# Combine two different object arrays into one

Tags: jq

I have two JSON object arrays:

```json
[
  {
    "foo": "foo1"
  },
  {
    "foo": "foo2"
  },
]
```

```json
[
  {
    "bar": "bar1"
  },
  {
    "bar": "bar2"
  },
  {
    "bar": "bar3"
  },
  {
    "bar": "bar4"
  },
]
```

I would like to combine these into one array of objects which would end up looking like this:

```json
[
  {
    "foo": "foo1"
    "bar": "bar1"
  },
  {
    "foo": "foo1"
    "bar": "bar2"
  },
  {
    "foo": "foo1"
    "bar": "bar3"
  },
  {
    "foo": "foo1"
    "bar": "bar4"
  },
  {
    "foo": "foo2"
    "bar": "bar1"
  },
  {
    "foo": "foo2"
    "bar": "bar2"
  },
  {
    "foo": "foo2"
    "bar": "bar3"
  },
  {
    "foo": "foo2"
    "bar": "bar4"
  },
]
```

This would generate the GitHub Actions matrix I need.

I'm struggling to get the desired output. `jq -s 'transpose | map(add)'` is kind of close.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can just use `+` on each item of both arrays. Assuming the two arrays are stored in variables `$a` and `$b`, then it'd be:

```bash
jq '[$a[] + $b[]]'
```

```json
[
  {
    "foo": "foo1",
    "bar": "bar1"
  },
  {
    "foo": "foo2",
    "bar": "bar1"
  },
  {
    "foo": "foo1",
    "bar": "bar2"
  },
  {
    "foo": "foo2",
    "bar": "bar2"
  },
  {
    "foo": "foo1",
    "bar": "bar3"
  },
  {
    "foo": "foo2",
    "bar": "bar3"
  },
  {
    "foo": "foo1",
    "bar": "bar4"
  },
  {
    "foo": "foo2",
    "bar": "bar4"
  }
]
```

[Demo](https://jqplay.org/s/PuoGYLlmkeC)

You may change the order of the array by flipping the summands as in `[$b[] + $a[]]`. The order with each object should matter as they are identical comparisonwise.